Problem creating a lending program
I am creating a lending program in anchor (solana) , but i don't understand the depositCollaterial and acceptCollaterial, how would i make the solana program to accept a user usdc (depositCollaterial) , and also when another user want to lend money (acceptCollaterial)

could you share the code if it's from a tutorial, link it too, please.

it is not a tutorial...It is a project, i am trying to work on (lending protocol), in essence ,how do i make the solana program , accept usdc from users, and also allows users to borrow usdc from the solana program
